# Filling an array with random vector2's in libGdx

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

I was trying to fill the array "stars" with random vector2's, when I had a problem while testing two apparently similar codes.

Head

```
Array<Vector2> stars;
int numStars;
```

First Code

```
public void initStars() {

    int a = 100;
    int b = 120;
    numStars = (int) (a * b * 0.01f);
    stars = new Array<Vector2>(numStars);
    Random rand = new Random();
    Vector2 star = new Vector2();

    for (int i = 0 ;i <numStars ;i++){
        star.set(rand.nextInt(a),rand.nextInt(b));
        stars.add(star);           
    }
}
```

Second Code

```
public void initStars() {

    int a = 100;
    int b = 120;
    numStars = (int) (a * b * 0.01f);
    stars = new Array<Vector2>(numStars);
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0 ;i <numStars ;i++){
        Vector2 star = new Vector2();
        star.set(rand.nextInt(a),rand.nextInt(b));
        stars.add(star);           
    }
}
```

The first didn't work, just fill the array with the last random vector generated in the loop, ie. all vectors in the array were equal, the second worked perfectly, my question is, why this happens, if the two codes are apparently equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first segment of code couldn't possibly work.  Take a closer look:

```
Vector2 star = new Vector2();

for (int i = 0 ;i <numStars ;i++){
    star.set(rand.nextInt(a),rand.nextInt(b));
    stars.add(star);           
}
```

You create the vector **ONCE**, and then keep assigning it new coordinates, then add it to the collection.  When you call `set()`, you're setting the value of the same vector (because you're still referencing the same vector).

The result is that you store the same vector in the collection `numStars` times, which is exactly what you notice.

Maybe to make this more concrete, what you're creating in the first scenario is essentially this:

```
stars = [starA, starA, starA, ..., starA]
```

While the second one is this:

```
stars = [starA, starB, starC, ..., starZ]
```

If you call `starA.set()`, in the first case, you're not only modifying the star you're adding; you're modifying **every star you put in before it** (because they are the same star!).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not equivalent. In Java, when data structures are used, only *pointers* are passed, not the actual objects.

Therefore, in your first code segment, you only have **one** actual `Vector2` object which is repeatedly added to the `Array`. Thus, each of the elements in the `Array` point to the *same object* and they will all have the same value. This is equal to the last value assigned to the `star` variable.

The second code segment, however, does work because **each point has it's own `Vector2` object** meaning each element in the `Array` points to a *different object* which has it's own value assigned randomly when it is created.